# From "$\text{lim inf}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 $" to "$\text{lim}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 $" (liminf to lim)

Tags: sequences-and-series, normed-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Consider the following:

> If $\ \ \text{lim inf}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 \ \ $ and $\ \ \text{lim}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|^2=0\ \ $ then $\ \ \text{lim}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 $

My question is

1. If **getting rid of "$\text{lim inf}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 $ "**, does it still hold?
2. Since $\|x(k)\|\geq0$, can we say "$\text{lim sup}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 $ **implies** $\text{lim}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 $"

---

If consider the following graph, it follows that "$\text{lim inf}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 $" does not imply $\text{lim}_{k\rightarrow\infty} \|x(k)\|=0 $ obviously.

Note: In my case, the wave should be above $0$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your statements are correct.  It is indeed sufficient to have $\|x(k)\|^2 \to 0$ or $\limsup \|x(k)\| = 0$.